# PostGIS Raster performances

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, ndvi, postgis-raster

I ingested two Landsat images into PostGIS database using :

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 28356 -M -t 100x100 LS7_20150425_B40.tif public.red | psql -d postgres -U postgres
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 28356 -M -t 100x100 LS7_20150425_B50.tif public.nir | psql -d postgres -U postgres
```

Ingestion is going fast : around 20 seconds for each insertion.
When I did the same without tiling (-t) and vacuum (-M), it took about the same duration.

Then I want to compute a NDVI raster table from PostGIS using the following SQL command :

```
CREATE TABLE public.ndvi AS
SELECT ST_MapAlgebraExpr(a.rast, 1, b.rast, 1, '([rast1] - [rast2]) / ([rast1] + [rast2])::float', '32BF') AS rast
FROM public.nir  a, public.red b;
```

If I am not using the tiling/vacuum options at the ingestion, the NDVI raster table is computed in about 3 minutes. With the tiling and vacuum options, the NDVI raster table is computed **in about one hour** ! Am I missing something here ?

I decided to use the tiling option to improve the performances when displaying rasters in QGIS but if the tiling slows things down when doing some calculations there is no interest anymore to do it this way.

Comment: OK I have understood my mistake... I thought that the selection in the SQL statement was smart enough to make the calculation on intersecting rasters. It is not the case, so it was doing the computation on every possible couples.

Comment: Glad you found the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct SQL statement is the following :

```
CREATE TABLE public.ndvi AS
SELECT ST_MapAlgebraExpr(arast, 1, brast, 1, '([rast1] - [rast2]) / ([rast1] + [rast2])::float', '32BF') AS rast
FROM (SELECT a.rast as arast, b.rast as brast FROM public.nir a INNER JOIN public.red b ON a.rid = b.rid) as joined;
```

It takes into account the tiling used when ingesting data into PostGIS using raster2pgsql